# NextJS - Router.push with props for page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my React app, I've used `import Router from 'next/router'` to move to another page with: `Router.push('/form')`.

However on `form` where I have the function component:

```
export default function FormOnSubmitExample() { ... }
```

I want to be able to pass some props into it (these have already been gathered on the first page/from where I'm directing from.

How is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want get some `props` in certain page component, pass value to `router.query` is appropriate.

Comment: So that passes it via URL - assume the values I had were a little longer, I guess the only other option is local storage?

Comment: Depends on what do you want. If you data should be keep after user revisit your page, you can store it via `URL` or `localStorage` or `cookie`. If you don't need to keep data permanent, just store it in `redux` or `sessionStorage` is fine.